# Input Box Range is not taking for Find function

Tags: vba, find, inputbox

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim FindStr As String

FindStr = "ABG Sec India BP PBT"

'Get Range address from the User to get the PBT Input from
On Error Resume Next
Set MyRange = Excel.Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the PBT range e.g A5:M20 from NPV Sheet", _
            Title:="PBT Range", _
            Type:=8)


On Error GoTo 0

'Copy the PBT Number from the next worksheet in My Range

For i = 1 To 7
    Range("d5").Offset(i, 0) = Worksheets("NPV ").Range(MyRange).Find(what:=FindStr).Offset(0, i + 2)
Next i
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question yet. Please read [ask]. Also please [edit] your post and include where you got stuck or errors. What is wrong with your code? Please write a proper description of your problem.

Comment: If you step through with **F8** does `MyRange` have a value? Also does your sheet name really have the space at the end of it? `"NPV "`

Comment: yes, when do debug.print myrange.address it is generating the range the i selected i.e. $A$28:$J$33 from the NPV sheet;

Comment: `MyRange` is already a `Range`. `Range(MyRange)` therefore makes no sense. If you wanted to search the selected range, then use `= MyRange.Find(...).Offset(...)`. If you wanted to search the range on the "NPV" sheet that has the same address as the selected range, then use `Worksheets("NPV ").Range(MyRange.Address).Find(...).Offset(...)`.

Comment: Many thanks. This resolves.